# Multiple simple routing in route 53 doesn't work for https

Tags: amazon-web-services, https, routes

We created an application in nodejs for backend and react for front end uploaded in github and connected it to elastic beanstalk for backend and aws amplify for frontend. Purchased a domain in route 53 to make it https. We created separate record name for our front end and backend in route 53 but the record name for our backend is not yet secured. What might be the problem?

Comment: What about your SSL certficates? Did you setup your instance to server HTTPS connections?

Comment: yes, It's done. actually it work now in the front-end but the backend is not yet working its https. I don't know. Is it possible to have to single routing in route 53?